# How do I purchase cylinders of Hydrogen (H2) gas for person use?

Tags: gas, compressed-gases

I'm interested in building small model airships, and I would like to purchase a cylinder of H<sub>2</sub> gas to fill the envelopes with as is far cheaper and more effective than helium. I've contacted some local gas and welding supply stores in Central Texas, but they're not retailers and said they couldn't supply without an account or something with their company which I don't have. How do hobbyists buy gases for welding, etc.?

Comment: Set up an account with a weld supply shop.

Comment: You can make it by electrolysis pretty easily.